# C# 7.0 "deconstructor"

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I'm reading about [C# 7.0 new stuff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt790184?MC=Vstudio&MC=.NET&MC=MSAzure&MC=CSHARP&MC=DevOps), and I cannot grok, at least from the example given, what would be the usage for a "deconstructor".

Is it just syntactic sugar?

If someone could shed some light about it, that would be nice.

Comment: What is unclear about it? As to whether it's syntactic sugar: the page you link to is clear on it: "Obviously, you can call the Deconstruct method as you would have in C# 1.0. However, C# 7.0 provides syntactic sugar that significantly simplifies the invocation."

Comment: No need to fret about it, It is pretty much automatic.  Soon after you start working with the new tuple syntax you'll find a use for that sugar.

Comment: It seems like there's new syntax being added to C# just for feature parity with other languages, but adding dubious value and not making intent any clearer.

Comment: It's syntactic sugar that IMHO we don't want... This strikes me as one of those things that makes code harder to read and harder to understand purely to make it terser...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a part of the new tuple syntax - which has nothing to do with the Tuple<> classes - but is taking from functional programming.

Consider this class:

```
public class User
{
   public string Username { get; }
   public string FirstName { get; }
   public string LastName { get; }

   public User(string username, string firstName, string lastName)
   {
       // initialize properties
   }

   public void Deconstruct(out string username, out string firstName, out string lastName)
   {
       // initialize out parameters
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
var user = new User("foobaa", "foo", "baa");
```

Instead of

```
var username = user.Username;
var firstName = user.FirstName;
var lastName = user.LastName;
```

or

```
string username, firstName, lastName;
user.Deconstruct(out username, out firstName, out lastName);
```

You can write:

```
var (username, firstName, lastName) = user;

var fullName = $"{firstName} {lastName}";
```

**Update**

---

Another example that it might be used for, and this just speculations, I have not tried this, is together with pattern matching.

```
var users = new Dictionary<string, User>
{
    {"john", new User("jom", "John", "Malkovich") }
}
```

**C# 6**

```
User user;
users.TryGetValue("john", out user);
```

**C# 7 pattern matching**

```
users.TryGetValue("john", out User user);
```

**C# 7 deconstruct**

```
users.TryGetValue("john", out (username, firstname, lastname));
```

Comment: So you mean it's just syntactic sugar? I guess if the feature has been introduced in the language, it was for covering a specific need. If I understand you correctly, that need would be to access multiple properties of an object instance in one shot?

Comment: It might have something to do with the old `Tuple` types. Depending on the result of [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/13746), `Tuple` is likely going to have `Deconstruct`, so you will be able to write `var (x, y) = Tuple.Create(10, 20);`.

Comment: I also was just reading about this and a little unsure of its value. I don't doubt there may be value I'm not seeing, but would like to see better examples of it. Examples I've seen have deconstructed public properties from the object, and in fact those values of interest rightly should be public properties. I don't see the value, or even consider it "syntactic sugar", to add a line of code to declare and extract local variables rather than simply using the public properties of the object.

Comment: This would be mostly useful for things where you want multiple return values.. I am working on a data packer for instance where I can get the byte[] and length values with out having to Buffer.BlockCopy into a new data set to make the byte[]'s length value useful, now I just get told how many of the bytes in the array are the result. var (buffer, length) = Packer.GetBytes() .. no icky out vars.

Answer (score -1):

If memory serves, it also coincides with `ValueTuple<...>`, ad hoc tuples, which can, and frequently do, also get deconstructed, quite literally, all... the... time. That is,

```
var tuple = (1, true, "string"); // to bind them all
var (one, flag, s) = tuple;
```

Or if we formalized that to a proper class:

```
class Data
{
  public int Value { get; set; }

  public bool Flag { get; set; }

  public string Text { get; set; }

  public void Deconstruct(out int value, out bool flag, out string text) =>
    (value, flag, text) = (this.Value, this.Flag, this.Text);
}
```

From my limited experience with these little beasties, ad hoc tuples are helpful, and have their uses, to a point. Then there is a line between when that and a more formal class definition is in order, with one or perhaps a couple few deconstruction use cases being supported.

And so on.

HTH